# Rails: help me avoid having to use such deeply nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I've got really long nested routes like so:

```
# barracudas have many elephants
resources :barracudas do

  # elephants have any barracudas, and have many gloworms too
  resources :elephants do

    # gloworms have any elephants, and have many chimpanzees too
    resources :gloworm do

      # chimpanzees have many gloworms
      resources :chimpanzees do
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

As you can see there are a lot of `has_many, :through` relationships here, so it's hard to find a chimpanzees parent gloworm wihout a little help from the URL:

```
# chimpanzees_controller.rb
def show   
  @barracuda  = Barracuda.find(params[:barracuda_id])
  @elephant   = @barracuda.elephants.find(params[:elephant_id])
  @gloworm    = @elephant.gloworms.find(params[:gloworm_id])
  @chimpanzee = @gloworm.chimpanzees.find(params[:id])
end
```

I would like to hide the fact that my system has barracudas, I want to change the urls from:

```
http://lvh.me:3000/barracudas/1/elephants/32/gloworms/5/chimpanzees/3
```

to:

```
http://lvh.me:3000/elephants/32/gloworms/5/chimpanzees/3
```

Am I right in thinking that I just need to remove the nesting from the routes, and add a :barracuda_id to the session so that I can always find it in the controller? Something like this?

```
@barracuda = Barracuda.find(session[:barracuda_id])
```

What if I wanted to remove all mention of elephants and gloworms from the URLs too? I guess it would be the same idea right? Expiring session data will probably be the biggest job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can a chimpanzee belong to more than one gloworm (and so on up the chain)? If not, you can collapse your whole structure into unnested routes and use something like this in your Controller:

```
# chimpanzees_controller.rb
def show   
  @chimpanzee = Chimpanzee.find(params[:id])
  @gloworm    = @chimpanzee.gloworm
  @elephant   = @gloworm.elephant
  @barracuda  = @elephant.barracuda
  # Maybe do some checking on the current user to make sure the right Barracuda is loaded?
end
```

As long as you have `belongs_to` associations all the way up, you should be golden.

If you've got `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations anywhere in there, then you have to have the IDs from both sides of the association. Your session approach seems reasonable, although it can fall down if your users ever open multiple tabs to browse separate Barracudas.

Another approach could be composite IDs in your routes. Something like:

```
get "/chimpanzees/:barracuda_id-:elephant_id-:gloworm_id-:id" => "chimpanzee#show"
```

The URLs will look a little non-standard, but it disguises the objects you're dealing with.

Comment: I have has_and_belongs_to_many relations all the way up the chain, and I love the composite idea, I'll probably go with that. Thanks.